# How to fill a gridPane with textFields in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

In gluonhq javafx scenebuilder, what is the fastest way to fill all of the spots in a gridPane with textFields? I have a 12x12 grid, so filling it in by hand is not an option.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Filling a 12x12 grid by hand is not an option? I could have done that in the time it took me to write this comment :).  That being said, there is no way to do it in SceneBuilder. You could use a loop in code to populate the grid, though.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest, and only, way to do that in SceneBuilder is by hand, dragging-and-dropping a new TextField into each grid space.

This is a very simple task in Java code, however, with the use of a couple `for` loops:

```
        // Each Row
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            // Each column
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                gridPane.add(new TextField(), i, j);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code snippet can easily be added to the `initialize` method and has the benefit of not requiring 144=12*12 fields or gridpane children casting to be accessed: The `TextField`s can simply be added to a data structure of your choice...